# WordPress Login for multiple sites

Tags: wp-admin, login

i am facing a strange issue, i have around 450+ WordPress sites, hosted across multiple providers (some on shared hostingS, some on VPSs, around 8-9 different locations & providers)
But since last night, wordpress amdin login stopped working for almost 90% of the sites. 
It says wrong password, (i am 100% sure i am using correct password). These sites are not related / connected to one another anyway. & most of the sites are having exactly same issue.

Sometime (with some sites) if i am able to login it redirected to the link like below

http&colon;&sol;&sol;www&period;mywebsite&period;com&sol;wp-admin&sol;

Except the problem one thing is common between all sites, i am managing all these sites with https://managewp.com/

What can be the issue? or possible solution

Comment: first thing to try is another browser since you are the common denominator...

Comment: tried from different locations, different computers, different browsers, nothing helped.

Comment: Have you tried contacting ManageWP about this issue? It's highly unlikely that anything else is causing the problem if you've already tried logging in from different computers and browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted to managewp but no avail, they insisted there is some issue on hosting side & it was very hard to believed that suddenly 9 different hosting account had the issue? After long frustration & checking everything, my co-worker Wyatt rectified the issue. Cloudlare plugin was the culprit. Further info can be found here

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/bugs-in-1321-crash-wp-site?replies=10